# OpenGL and Unity failed to work together on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I have exported my game from Unity to Xcode and everything is ok, the game is running normally.

I decided to add one OpenGLView in the menus (build in Xcode) to make some transformations over a 3D plane with 2D texture, and then capture it in UIImage. Everything was ok, the image is taken, but when I enter in Unity environment I receive:

```
floomzer(9403,0x3fc1448c) malloc: *** mmap(size=1077534720) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
PlayerLoop called recursively!

(Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/6bc5f79e0a4296d6/Projects/../Runtime/Misc/Player.cpp Line: 1201)

PlayerLoop called recursively!

(Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/6bc5f79e0a4296d6/Projects/../Runtime/Misc/Player.cpp Line: 1201)
```

If I do not load the OpenGL part of the menu, but go straight to the Unity environment, the game starts normally.

Is it a conflict with Unity and my OpenGL-ES view?
Did my changes over the OpenGL state affect Unity OpenGL rendering?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but sounds like you need a deep understanding of Unity3D's EAGLView handling in AppController.mm.